Female assassin with a boyfriend who has the heart on the wrong side
This movie is Asian, probably Japanese. It is at least ten years old.
The story is as follows: a female assassin falls in love with a guy, but her boss wants the guy dead. He has situs inversus (i.e. his heart is on the right side of his torso). At one point she has to shoot him, so shoots him on the left side (the usual side for the heart). He survives.
I find the film similar to Point of No Return.
Note: Both answers currently provided have been checked and are not the film in question.

A problem - the heart is on the left side of the torso. Did the character definitely have his heart on the wrong side, or do you mean the assassin deliberately missed him by shooting him on the other side?

is fixed @AndrewMartin. thansk

You need to be clearer. How old? Are we talking 1950s? 1970s? 1990s? 2000s? Can you give anything else?

Actually, the heart is almost dead center in the chest, behind the breastbone. There is a portion that juts out into the left side of the chest, but it's less than a third of the total mass of the heart.

@JohnP, is a movie, not a documentary. :D

@JohnP: I didn't realise it was that little. That's actually very interesting.

@AndrewMartin I would say 90s, but can be early 00s or late 80s

The only other mention I could find at all for a character with dextrocardia (reversed heart) was "Wounded", and I can't confirm that. There is a wiki page for fictional characters with situs inversus (All organs reversed) here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_characters_with_situs_inversus

@AndrewMartin - It can vary with individual physiology, but at most (Barring birth defects or various disease states) 1/2 of the heart would be exposed.

Helena, a character on Orphan Black, is an assassin with Situs Inversus.

The movie you are looking for is Black Cat (aka Hei Mao) (1991) not Beyond Hypothermia.


Can you please explain why it's not the approved answer?

Thanks, I haven't watched yet but the synopsis seems more accurate

It sounds like Ninja Assassin.

Ninja Assassin is a 2009 American-German martial arts film directed by James McTeigue.


How the movie starts:

Raizo (Rain) is raised by the Ozunu Clan to become the most lethal
  ninja assassin in the world. As a child, Raizo (being an orphan) was
  taken in by Lord Ozunu (Sho Kosugi) and is enrolled in severe brutal
  training to become the next successor of their clan.

From the end of the film:

Mika, seemingly fatally wounded, is in fact saved by a quirk of birth:
  her heart is actually on the opposite side of her chest.

This is the trailer.

Is not that one.

@HélioSantos: Definitely? It matches everything you've said, including the heart defect.

her heart is ok. the boyfriend's heart is not. And the movies is not from 2000s

@HélioSantos: I can keep looking but check out the trailer in case. If it is definitely not that film, you need to update your question with more details. Approximate year, any famous quotes, any more story detail. Anything would be helpful

Seen the trailer. Is not that one. No explosion, no swords. I find the film similar to "Point of no return" (1993)

Beyond Hypothermia (1996)
"Sip si 32 dou" (original title)
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115665/

@Jelena I'm happy you got the right answer but link only answers are not encouraged in this site. If you could elaborate your answer with bit more info like adding the plot in your answer from the reference you've provided and also you could explain why you think this movie matches OP's description by providing dialogues or lines from the movie script would definitely fetch you more upvotes. Check other answers for examples. Good luck.

I think the movie in question might be Koibito wa sunaipâ - My lover is a Sniper (2004).
See this link if you still able to read in Portuguese language.
Here is the movie's IMDB page.

Welcome to the site! Your answer may be correct, but it would be great if you could add some excerpts from the IMDB, or any other information whatsoever to explain why this might be the answer. Feel free to take the Tour under the Help menu for more information on how the site works.

@AndrewMartin thank your for your help. I will try to make my next contributions in the right way. :)

Your contribution is an acceptable answer, so that's great. But the more info the better :)

Here is an English review - Makes no mention of a reversed heart, and not much else fits either: http://www.beyondhollywood.com/my-lover-is-a-sniper-2004-movie-review/




Is it this one? It's actually called "dextrocardia". I have dextrocardia. ran across that trailer and your question while researching my condition funny enough!

http://youtu.be/0CPcIDlMnB0

This question already have an accepted answer, that means user already got the movie he is searching for, have you noticed that?

Is it Reign of Assassins?

Drizzle/Zeng Jing tries to start a new life after she had betrayed her gang and hid the remains of monk.

I just saw the movie today.

Seems highly unlikely! This looks like a period movie involving primitive weaponry, whereas the OP has specifically mentioned that the girl shoots the guy. Can you point to the specific scene in the movie where this happens?
